# Firebug: how do I see GET parameters?

Tags: firebug

I'm using Firebug on Firefox 3.6.3 for Mac.

I want to use Firebug to view GET and POST parameters being passed. I have Firebug open at the  Net > XHR tab. The panel says 'Net panel activated'.

Yet if I then go to google.com and do a search, nothing appears in the XHR tab. (All the HTML, CSS etc appears fine in the other tabs.)

Where can I see the GET parameters being passed to Google in Firebug?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the All tab in the NET panel

POST parameters can be seen in the NET panel.  The first line is the page and if you click the down arrow to expand it, you can see the parameters under the section called "Post"

GET parameters can be seen in a similar way, on the expanded NET tab, its the section called "Params". Additionally, GET parameters will always be part of the url.  It's the set of parameters after the ? in the URL.

Comment: Spot on!  Although I had to click 'Console' and then enable 'Show Network Errors' in order to get the NET panel to appear.  This was on Firefox 3.6.8 and Firebug 1.5.4 on Ubuntu 10.

Comment: great answer, it really helps me. now i can see all my flash's back request/response in firebug, firebug rocks!!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do this in Firebug, but you could use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see the entire request and response.

Answer (score 0):

Within Firebug you can also select DOM->document->forms->Your Form Name

All of you input variables and their post values will be listed under there.

I hope that helps.