# Program to see data sent throught method post or get in Php

Tags: php, cakephp

I need to find a program for see that data are sent a thought the method Post or Get in PHP
without use $_POST and $_GET

Comment: I think you need the Firebug extension for Firefox. I didn't understand very well what you need.

Comment: Exactly . What you say. I don't want to imprime the variables in the code for see their value, but a program that show me this

Comment: *Exactly . What you say*, `Firebug` or `$_REQUEST` what do you mean now?

Comment: Why?... That question is very wage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$_REQUEST["my_variable"]`  for php ( server side )

If you want see in browser extension you can use **firebug** ( client side )

[Firebug: how do I see GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953289/firebug-how-do-i-see-get-parameters)